# Split files on folders into more folders with php

Tags: php, ssh, hosting, server

I had a problem lately and couldn't get a solution for it , i have 100,000 image in 1 folder in my server called

```
/Images/
```

inside this folder there are 100,000 image something like this:

```
/Images/image1.jpg
/Images/image2.jpg
/Images/image3.jpg
...
```

using cpanel file manger i cant compress these files and i cant open the Images folder it overtime and never open , even with filezilla and smartftp the Images folder shows only 10,000 image , so the best solution i have now is to split the folder into more folders and compress them as parts.

i want it to be done something like this :

```
/Images/part1/image1.jpg
/Images/part1/image2.jpg
/Images/part1/image3.jpg
...

/Images/part2/image10001.jpg
/Images/part2/image10002.jpg
/Images/part2/image10003.jpg
...

...
```

so at the end i will have 10 folders in each folder i have 10,000 image.

Can i do this using PHP ?

thanks.

Comment: 1. *Can i do this using PHP .* First error spotted! <- Change the dot to a question mark and you have an actual question in your post. 2. What have you tried so far? 3. Which pattern does this: `image10001.jpg` follows?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out .. i am not too good in php .. i couldnt even start myself ..

Comment: I'd start here http://php.net/opendir Open a handle to the directory and start cranking through the files. Perl might actually be better at this, but PHP will work too.

Comment: You could also write the PHP script like a shell script using system() or exec(), or you could write bash script do this as well. Lots of ways to skin this one, but you should probably start working on it and if you get stuck, ask a more specific question, this one is too broad.

Comment: yep .. thats a good start i can open new dir .. but how i copy 1st 10,000 image to that dir ..

Comment: @Rizier123 is celebrating their OCD victory. ;-)

Comment: This could work. http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: thanks for your help .. i will start working on the php .. and do my best :) .. if i get stuck thn u smart guys are here to help me out :)..

Comment: It shouldn't take more than a 20 lines of code. It just might take a long time to do all of the copying and cleaning things up.

Comment: its my mistake that i put thm all in 1 file haha they are just stuck there .. cant open cant download ..

Comment: Yes, most, if not all, files systems have a limit on the number of files allowed per directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

1. I use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all files in the directory which matches the pattern

2. I created chunks of 10 with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) out of the array with all files. So i converted the array e.g. `Array ( [0] => ... [2000] => ...)` to an array which looks like: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ... [9] => ...) )`

3. I created as many folders as you have chunks with [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

4. And at the end I moved all files in the directory's with [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
<?php

    //Configuration
    $folderPattern = "part";
    $chunkSize = 10;
    $path = "images/";

    //get images
    $files = glob($path . "*.*");
    $chunks = array_chunk($files, $chunkSize);
    
    //create folders
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($chunks); $i++) {
        if(!file_exists($path . $folderPattern . $i))
            mkdir($path . $folderPattern . $i, 0700);
    }

    //move images
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($chunks); $i++) {
        for($x = 0; $x < count($chunks[$i-1]); $x++) {
            rename($path . basename($chunks[$i-1][$x]), $path . $folderPattern . $i . "/" . basename($chunks[$i-1][$x])); 
            echo $path . basename($chunks[$i-1][$x]) . " -> " . $path . $folderPattern . $i . "/" . basename($chunks[$i-1][$x]) . "<br />";
        }
    }

?>
```

Depending on your knowledge about basic php you may want to look into this:

- [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
- [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
- [if statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
- [control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

**Answer tested:**

- With 10'000 images
- Same configuration as in the answer
- Image size: 31'503 Bytes
- Time of execution: 15-17 sec (average: 16.189925909042 sec)

#### EDIT:

To change your folder structure from:

> X folders with 10 images

to:

> 10 folders with X images

This script convert's X folders to X/10 folders e.g. 8139 -> 813 folders. So if you want to convert 8139 -> 813 run it 2x and if you want 8139 -> 81 run it 3x.

**Note:** If a file already exists e.g. `/images/part1/xy.jpg` and you want to move the file into this folder, it automatically appends `- TEMP-[random number]` to the name so it doesn't get lost. As example if you now want to move the file: `/images/partXY/xy.jpg` into the folder from above the file get's renamed to: `/images/part1/xy.jpg - TEMP-906222766`. So you can spot these files easy and rename it to what you want.

(If you want a full explanation to this code let me know in the comments)

```
<?php

    //Since it can take a few seconds more than 30 and default is (mostly) 30
    set_time_limit(120);


    //Configuration
    $path = "images/";
    $chunkSize = 10;
    
    //Get all dirs
    $dirs = glob($path . "*");

    //Get all files
    foreach($dirs as $dir)
        $files[] = glob($dir . "/*.*");
    
    //Define MAX folders
    $files = array_chunk($files, $chunkSize);

    
    foreach($files as $key => $innerArray) {
        $baseFolder = dirname(str_replace($path, "", array_column($innerArray, 0)[0]));
        
        for($i = 1; $i < count($innerArray); $i++) {
            foreach($files[$key][$i] as $file) {
                if(file_exists($path . $baseFolder . "/" . basename($file)))
                    rename($file, $path . $baseFolder . "/" . basename($file) . " - TEMP-" . mt_rand());
                else
                    rename($file, $path . $baseFolder . "/" . basename($file));
                
                echo $file . " -> " . $path . $baseFolder . "/" . basename($file) . "<br />";
            }
            
            //Delete dir
            rmdir($path . str_replace($path, "", dirname($files[$key][$i][0])));
            echo "<br /><br />Removed: " . $path . str_replace($path, "", dirname($files[$key][$i][0])) . "<br /><br />";
        }

    }

?>
```

**Answer tested:**

- With 10'000 images | à 1'000 folders e.g. 10 images per folder
- Same configuration as in the answer
- Image size: 31'503 Bytes
- Script called: 2 times:

  1. 1'000 folders -> 100
  2. 100 folders   -> 10
- Time of execution: 29-33 sec (average: 31.29639005661  sec)

Comment: @MadianMalfi You're welcome! Yeah, I'm interested too if and how fast this works with 100k images. (Just configure everything to your needs) And then let me know if it worked

Comment: it did work and it was very fast , but i have 8139 part folder now .. dont know whats wrong .. how do i merge all dirs back to 1 now :(

Comment: @MadianMalfi What do you mean with merge all dirs back to 1? So now you have folders part1 ... part8139 with 10images per folder?

Comment: exactly i want the opposite .. 10 folders each folder up to 10k or whatever .. haha.. thank you for your help :) ..

Comment: i think i should merge all files again and edit $chunkSize = 10; into 10000 .. then it will work .. right ?

Comment: how i will merge them haha .. does rename work ? .. if so then how can i rename all folders with same name ?

Comment: @MadianMalfi So what is the situation now? You have 1...8139 folders with 10 images and your goal is 1...10 folders with 10'000 images?

Comment: my goal is 1...10 folders ..each folder how many images doexnt matter but in my case it would be around 8139 images i guess

Comment: @MadianMalfi And right now you have 1...8139 folders with 10 images each ?

Comment: is it possible to merge folders using php ?

Comment: @MadianMalfi Should be otherwise make it easy and get all images out of the folders and to my script again, but i will try it

Comment: how i would get all images from 8139 folder .. that would take lifetime lol

Comment: @MadianMalfi Give me a hot minute I will try to write a little script for you :D

Comment: @MadianMalfi updated my answer. Hope it helps, solves your problem and if you have any other questions just ask

Comment: thank you very much .. i will test it out . also i made solution by my self hehe i am getting better on this .. will post the solution and tell me how is it .. 
thanks youoo

Answer (score 0):

anther solution to extract all folders(8139) files(10) into 1 file back with (81390) file i Used this.

**NOTE: THIS WILL EXTRACT ALL FOLDERS FILES INTO 1 FOLDER WITH ALL FILES**

```
$dir = "images/";

foreach(glob($dir . "*") as $file) 
{
       foreach(glob($file . "/*") as $inside)
       {
           rename("$inside","$dir" . basename($inside));
       }
       rmdir($file);

}

?>
```